# Google Script trouble with arrays

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm building an app on top of Google Spreadsheets. Using GoogleScript and the 'HTML service' to make the UI. Having trouble with working with JavaScript arrays in client side pages. They are not working for me. Arrays are working fine in server side code found in 'Code.gs'. They don't work in served HTML.

The following sample code, gives an error in FireBug: **"TypeError: Cannot set "ary""**

```
<p id=sample></p>

<script>
ary = new Array();
ary = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
peter1 = ary[1];

$('#sample').html(peter1);

</script>
```

Comment: Is that the whole html file? You're using jQuery, but don't have the library included. The array assignment works fine in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GUSat/).

Comment: Your correct Mogsdad, I hadn't included all the code. 95% of it was irrelevant. I did have the JQuery library called. Figured out the issue and posted an answer below.

Comment: Ah, yes, the joys of Caja! I'm glad you figured it out. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Google enforces Caja Sanitization (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html-service-caja). One of the requirements is ' requires that variables be declared before use'. I hadn't done that.

Got the following code to work.

```
<script>
var ary = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var peter1 = ary[1];

$('#sample').html(peter1);

</script>
```